# How to do multiple OR queries in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
db.Event.find({
  startDate: {
    $or: [
      {$and: [
          {$gte: '2013-05-12'}
          {$lt: '2013-05-13'}
      ]},
      {$and: [
          {$gte: '2013-05-12'}
          {$lt: '2013-05-13'}
      ]}
    ]
  },
  foo: {
    ...
  }
});
```

Basically I have a bunch of filters, and one of them is `startDate`, which needs to be matching one of the `$and` groups that contain a range for date.

Comment: You still shouldn't be using $or but $in (so replace $or with $in) and remove $and entirely - $and is the default for multiple conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.User.find({
    $or: [{firstName:'Foo'}, {firstName:'Bar'}]
  ,
    $or: [{lastName:'Baz'}, {lastName:'Qux'}]
  }
});
```

you need the curly braces inside the square or braces

Comment: Does this do 2 queries? I'm running this from code using a library that doesn't have this so does this just mean 2 queries?

Comment: @Ahmed it should jut be one, I don't know anything about mogodb, I just googled it because it looked like an easy question to get rep from.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `$or` correctly - that's for unioning whole queries.

In this case, you just want `$in`.

```
db.User.find({
  firstName: {
    $in: ['Foo', 'Bar']
  },
  lastName: {
    $in: ['Baz', 'Qux']
  }
});
```

Edit: Per your edit, you need to update your example code with an actual example then, because as given, your problem is solved with `$in`.

Comment: Sorry, I think my first code sample wasn't good enough so I updated. How would you apply your approach to the updated version?